# Xamarin cross platform windows project error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform

[image][image]

So I am creating a new cross platform app that should incorporate iOS, Android, and windows. But for some reason I get this error (attached). I am able to get Android and IOS projects and am able to build/compile them W/O any problem.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot develop Win10 apps on not win10 machine

Comment: The screen shot shows that you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7. That's not qualified for UWP projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. Is there any way i can make UWP projects work with Windows 7?